# Deleting multiple models & extending Eloquent Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am making a general function which takes attributes and deletes all models having those. It is defined in a class called `BaseModel` which extends `Eloquent` while all other models extend it.

The models get retrieved but deleting them generates a 500 but there is no exception details which can be caught through `try catch` block even. It seems that the app gets aborted on the line altogether.

**Code**

```
/**
 * @param string|array $attributes
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $operator
 * @return int
 */
public static function deleteAllWithAttributes
    ($attributes, $value = '', $operator = '=')
{
    $instance = new static;
    if (is_array($attributes)) {
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            $instance = $instance->where($key, $operator, $value);
        }
    } else {
        $instance = $instance->where($attributes, $operator, $value);
    }
    $models = $instance->get();
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        try {
            $model->delete();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
    return count($models);
}
```

**Usage**

```
`[Model class name]::deleteAllWithAttributes([Attribute name], [value], [operator]);`
```

**OR**

`[Model class name]::deleteAllWithAttributes([Attributes associative array], [operator]);`

Comment: look in log file for more information - path ```storage/logs/``` Also, you can simplify deleting, ```$instance->delete()``` without retive all items. And removing operation will return count of removed objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't tell you what's the error, but definitely this is not the way to go:

1. You're fetching **N** rows and create **N** models
2. Then you delete them one by one calling **N** queries

All this is redundant and won't scale. It may be slow even with not that many rows, since delete is much more time consuming than select. Instead run 2 queries - 1st for `count` and 2nd for `delete`.

Also I would `extend` the `Eloquent\Builder` instead of creating static method for flexibility:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class DeleteAllScope implements ScopeInterface {

    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @return int
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->macro('deleteAllWhere', function(
                          Builder $builder, 
                          $column, 
                          $operator = '=', 
                          $value = null, 
                          $boolean = 'and'
        )
        {
            if (is_array($column))
            {
                $builder->whereNested(function($query) use ($column, $operator, $value)
                {
                    foreach ( (array)$column as $field => $value)
                    {
                        $query->where($field, $operator, $value);
                    }
                }, $boolean);
            }
            else
            {
                $builder->where($column, $operator, $value, $boolean);
            }

            $count = $builder->count();

            $builder->delete();

            return $count;
        });
    }

    // no need for implementation, just to satisfy the interface
    public function remove(Builder $builder) {}
}
```

and use in `BaseModel`:

```
//  Base model
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new \Your\Namespace\DeleteAllScope);
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
SomeModel::deleteAllWhere('column', '=', 'value'); // 8

$wheres = ['col' => 'val', 'other_col' => 'other_val'];
SomeModel::deleteAllWhere($wheres); // 1

// and lets you add more complex constraints
SomeModel::whereIn('id', [1,10,15,20])->deleteAllWhere($wheres); // 3

SomeModel::whereIn('id', [1,10,15,20])->deleteAllWhere($wheres, null, '<>', 'or');
// DELETE FROM table WHERE id in (1,10,15,20) OR (col <> val AND other_col <> other_val);
```

Comment: Is this approach limited to where clauses only?

Comment: Are there any implications to such approach?

Comment: 1. You can do whatever you like there, not only `where` - in fact, there's also `delete` called ;)  2. In what way? You extend the `Eloquent\Builder` in runtime, ie. when the query is instantiated on the `Model` where you add that global scope (in this case in every derived from `BaseModel`). If you're not familiar with global scopes, read this http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/